# Sorting and filtering in DataGridView windows application

Tags: windows, vb.net, forms

Hi I am looking to implement sorting and filtering in datagrid view of windows form. So far articles read shows to create a button and on click of that do sorting  and filtering. But I want that functionality on grid headers. Are there any third party available that provide us with this feature or is there any other in build way?
Please guide.

Comment: It is built in. Just click the header when running to sort.

Comment: [Building a Drop-Down Filter List for a DataGridView Column Header Cell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/aa480727(v=msdn.10))

Answer (score 0):

the datagridview has alongside the headertext sortingsoptions.

Filtering goes by filtering the datasource for example the dataview o fa table